# What does diiferent colours in orbital path seen in the CRS 21 launch video indicate?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, identify-this-object, orbital-elements

The SpaceX broadcast of Falcon 9 - CRS 21 launch showed the orbital path of the vehicle differently than previous videos. Separate green lines and rectangualar boxes were visible.

What additional details can be inferred from the image?

[Youtube Video Link](https://youtu.be/4xJAGFR_N-c?t=1899)

[image: Cropped, brightened and sharpened detail]

[image: ScreenShot of the video with the doubt highlighted in red circle]

Comment: This is a different question but you may find the answer interesting: [What is the extra moving and disappearing line in the animation in the BulgariaSat-1 webcast?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22084/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for adding the picture with arrows. BulgariaSat-1 was launched to GTO so the path disappearing is obvious as apogee was being raised. But CRS missions operate in LEO.

Comment: One way to answer this would be to look for a solution in [flightclub.io](https://flightclub.io/build/choose-template) The site has been updated since I last used it, one used to be able to click on a launch that's happened and see [Declan](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/21025/declan-murphy)'s finished simulation of it, but I'm not sure those are routinely available now or if they want us to do it ourselves. :-)  (see also [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26686), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27230))

Comment: Given the "Jump" where blue ==green when crossing the ISS orbit path, my uneducated guess is that green is the intended path and blue is a "safety zone" of allowable diversion.